# One contract to another contract interaction analysis

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-invocation

I tried contract interaction using following code:

```
contract C2 { 
    function aFunction(uint aParameter) returns(uint) {
    return (10);
    }
}
contract C1 { 
    function call (uint aParameter) returns(uint){
        C2 c2 = new C2();
    return c2.aFunction(aParameter);
    }
}
```

It worked for me. Then i changed `return c2.aFunction(aParameter);` to `return c2;` It returned me an address (suppose c2_addr). I executed `eth.getCode(c2_addr);` It just returned "0x". Now i have following questions:

1. I just called the "call" function of C1 without using `sendTransaction()`. So how the line `C2 c2 = new C2();` is executed.
2. Contract C2 is mined or not.If yes, then who deployed it as i invoked the function as `.call()` and why there is no bytecode in blockchain regarding this contract. And if C2 is not mined, how it is possible to invoke its function.

Answer (score 1):

What client are you using?

Replacing

```
return c2.aFunction(aParameter);
```

with

```
return c2;
```

in contract **C1** does not [compile](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-latest.js) since it's an object type returned by a method declared to return unsigned integers (**uint**).

As of now, you can [return](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions.html#can-a-contract-function-return-a-struct) objects only within internal function calls and not to a remote client.

**Edit:**

I've run the code. The "address" that you are getting is not an address, but a conversion to bytes of the **c2** contract instance.

Comment: I am using GETH. I changed return type as "address" and i checked it from online solidity browser, there was no compilation error.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot in the question. @Sebi

Comment: See edit. The address returned does not belong to any contract but it's a sequence of bytes of the contract's instance c2.

Comment: Contract C2 is mined or not? if not then how its functions are available, if yes what is its contract address?

Comment: Both contracts are mined. You can see their address in the lower right pane in solidity browser (for example: C1 at 0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a (memory))

Comment: You are not returning a contract object c2 but a few raw bytes from it.

Comment: I just created C1 . There is no address regarding C2. And also how can i see it on geth. I repeat who mined C2 and what is its address? @Sebi I have added the remaining screen .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43183/discussion-between-sebi-and-a-k).